# JJTree Token Manager Declarations

Tags: java, token, abstract-syntax-tree, javacc

Hi everyone I have the following code in my .jjt file for my abstract syntax tree for checking track if where the nodes are made within the file that is passed to it but I cannot access this variable from my semantic checker class.
The code is bellow and any help would be appreciated! I've tried everything and I'm losing hope at this stage. 
This is the integer in the .jjt file i'd like to access
TOKEN_MGR_DECLS :

```
{
    static int commentNesting = 0;
    public  static int linenumber = 0;


}

SKIP : /*STRUCTURES AND CHARACTERS TO SCAPE*/
{
 " "
|  "\t"
|  "\n" {linenumber++;}
|  "\r"
|  "\f"
}
```

An example of one of my nodes

```
void VariableDeclaration() #VariableDeclaration : {Token t; String id; String type;}
{
    t = <VARIABLE> id = Identifier() <COLON> type = Type() 

}
```

My semantic checker class

```
public class SemanticCheckVisitor implements "My jjt file visitor" {
    public Object visit(VariableDeclaration node, Object data) {
        node.childrenAccept(this, data);
        return data;
    }
```

How would it be possible to get the linenumber which this node was declared?
Thanks everyone.

}

Answer (score 1):

You can see an example of this in the Teaching Machine's Java parser, which is [here](https://github.com/theodore-norvell/the-teaching-machine-and-webwriter/tree/master/trunk/tm/src/tm/javaLang/parser).

First you need to modify your `SimpleNode` type to include a field for the line number.  In the TM I added a declaration

```
private SourceCoords myCoords ;
```

where `SourceCoords` is a type that includes not only the line number, but also information about what file the line was in.  You can just use an `int` field. Also in `SimpleNode` you need to declare some methods like this

```
public void setCoords( SourceCoords toSet ) { myCoords = toSet ; }
public SourceCoords getCoords() { return myCoords ; }
```

You might want to declare them in the `Node` interface too.

Over in your `.jjt` file, use the option

```
NODE_SCOPE_HOOK=true;
```

And declare two methods in your parser class

```
void jjtreeOpenNodeScope(Node n) {
    ((SimpleNode)n).setCoords( new SourceCoords( file, getToken(1).beginLine ) ) ;
}
void jjtreeCloseNodeScope(Node n) {
}
```

Hmm.  I probably should have declared the methods in `Node` to avoid that ugly cast.

---

One more thing, you are keeping count of the lines yourself. It's better the get the line number from the token, like I did.  Your counter will generally by one token ahead.  But when the parser looks ahead, it could be several tokens ahead.

If the token manager isn't keeping count of the lines correctly, then use your own count, but communicate it to the parser through an extra added field in the `Token` class.

Generally it's a bad idea to compute anything in the token manager and then use it in the parser unless its information you store in the tokens.